# Users need to create dynamic rules that apply to other users access to the group

Tags: t-sql, database-design, dynamic-data, business-logic, rule-engine

Okay so here is "in a nutshell" what I'm trying to accomplish...

Users of my application can go and create a new group.  They can specify criteria about other users which they will allow/deny to determine who is allowed to join the group.

Example:
Age: 12 - 16 yrs old
Height: 5 - 6 feet

The data table that stores the rules would be like:
Allow or Deny Flag (Y/N)
AgeStart: 12
AgeEnd: 16
HeightStart: 5
HeightEnd: 6

We would then need to check if the user meets the criteria to determine if they are allowed to join the group.

Does this make sense?
There can also be EXCEPTION rules which go against it...
such as first "Allow: Y" might be Ages 12 to 30 but a second record might be added to Deny ages 25 to 28 so the user would have to meet both criteria to enter.

Any takers on this one?

Comment: sounds trivial - what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store the rules in your database using whatever kind of [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Specific_Language) makes sense to you, but SQL is not a solution for interpreting or enforcing the rules.

It'll be far easier to fetch the rules field into your app and interpret it there.  You'll have access to feature-rich parser libraries to interpret the rule, and easier ways to write OO code to apply it.

Since you only need to run the rule as a user tries to join a group, it shouldn't be a great performance cost to run a query to fetch the rule definition.  It'll certainly be a lot *less* costly than trying to implement a rule parser and enforcer in SQL!

Another way of thinking about this is:  **a database stores data, not code**.  You can fudge this by storing the definition of rules as strings in the database, but let the database treat these as verbatim strings, not try to integrate them as code that the RDBMS can execute.

Comment: I disagree.  As long as you want to be able to access the database from multiple applications, you *definitely* want the database to contain *all the logic* required to ensure that the relevant contracts offered to the applications are met.  Another way to look at this is **databases should encapsulate raw data and provide interfaces to that data, whether through views, stored procedures, or other methods.**

Comment: @ChrisTravers, have you implemented a custom business rules DSL parser in TSQL?  I maintain it would be easier to implement such in a library which is used by each of your multiple applications.

Comment: Why would you do it in TSQL?  Do it in .net as a function your TSQL functions can call within the SQL Server backend.  This way you could access the same code from a .Net client, a Linux/Perl client and the like.

Comment: @ChrisTravers, then it's in code, not in the database, and I have no objection.  What I was cautioning against is storing rules as data, and expecting to enforce rules through SQL expressions.

Comment: Its not in the database?  Where else would .net stored procedures be? Thinking of something like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12907/Simple-Stored-Procedures-in-NET (and yes, the records could be stored in the database, but they'd be parsed in whatever language you'd like via a functional interface exposed to SQL).

Comment: @ChrisTravers, I mean if you try to store the code for business rules in a VARCHAR, and then use SUBSTRING and CASE and so on to apply conditional behavior in an SQL expression based on "rules" encoded in the VARCHAR. That's what I mean by mixing code within data.  Your code should be implemented in .NET or whatever you want.  You can get *values* from the database, but the *logic* of what to do with those values should be fixed in your code.